# How to resize an image programmatically when creating node?

Tags: 7, media

I have created a content type with an image field. I have to add the content type programmatically.  From my form submit function I can get the `fid` like:

```
$product_image = $form_state['values']['announced_product_image'];
```

**I'm wondering how I can programmatically resize an image when creating a node.**

I have tried:

```
$test = file_load($product_image);
$img = image_load($test->uri);
image_resize($img, 200, 200);
```

But the image is not **saving** as 200x200.

Comment: Why not use the core imagecache module ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't forget to use [image_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!image.inc/function/image_save/7) after you've resized it!

Comment: duh, that did it! i was wondering why my changes weren't persisting....ty